# making quickly application launcher run as root

Tags: 14.04, quickly

I want to make an application using quickly, and I want to make the launcher of this application run as root.
 How can I do that??

Answer (score 0):

You can use launchers. What distribution do you use?
Look here to know how to create a launcher on desktop: [how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop).
In the command space, type

```
gksudo application_name
```

if it is a GUI, or

```
sudo application_name
```

if it runs in terminal.

Mark as executable:

```
chmod +x launcher_name
```

Or, Right click and select Mark as executable.

Comment: I added gksudo to the applicationname.desktop.in at the option Exec. but when I packaged it and installed it the gksudo removed from /usr/share/applications/applicationname.desktop !!